# Troubleshooting VBA - Merge only specific, multi worksheets from a selected folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have two issues with this code:

1. I want to copy a specific sheet, rather than all sheets in the workbooks
2. Some of the source workbooks have a macro in them, this throws a 'Excel Security Notice' which interrupts the execution of the code and all worksheets don't copy over

**Issue 1 target behaviour:**
I want to select files from a folder and have a specific worksheet copied over into my reporting template. This worksheet is always in tab position 1 and always contains "*current and closed*".

With the below code I have found online, it functions, but brings all worksheets from the source workbooks, including hidden sheets. I only want either the first tab, or the tab containing "*current and closed*" to be copied over.

**Issue 2 target behaviour:**
I want the code to ignore/evade the security notice so that the migration of source worksheets that have a macro in them is uninterrupted. I don't mind if the macro in the source workbooks is disabled as they aren't required in the consolidated reporting workbook

Thanks for your collective brain power!

---

Sub mergeFiles()
    'Merges all files in a folder to a main file.
    'https://professor-excel.com/merge-excel-files-combine-workbooks-one-file/#Method_4_Merge_files_with_a_simple_VBA_macro

```
'Define variables:
Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim mainWorkbook, sourceWorkbook As Workbook
Dim tempWorkSheet As Worksheet

Set mainWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'Allow the user to select multiple workbooks
tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True

numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

'Loop through all selected workbooks
For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count

    'Open each workbook
    Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)

    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy each worksheet to the end of the main workbook
    For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets
        tempWorkSheet.Copy after:=mainWorkbook.Sheets(mainWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
    Next tempWorkSheet

'Close the source workbook without saving changes in the source workbooks
sourceWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

Next i
```

End Sub

Comment: Get rid of the `For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets` and change the `tempWorkSheet` in the next line to `sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I tried this and got compile error 'Invalid Next control variable reference'. I think it doesn't like the line below which still refers to tempWorkSheet?

Comment: Get rid of the entire line `For Each tempWorkSheet In sourceWorkbook.Worksheets` and the `Next tempWorkSheet`.

Comment: Super! This worked. Thanks, @BigBen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suppress warnings, turn off alerts, open the workbook as ReadOnly and don't update the link:

```
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i), False, True
```

To act only on a particular worksheet, add conditional check within the `For...next` loop based on your priority whether "current and closed" is higher priority than the 1st tab, or you want to copy both. To check the worksheet name, use `tempWorkSheet.Name` and `Instr()` function to check whether it contains "current and closed".

Remember to re-enable alerts at the end of your function by:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```